# [PHP/JavaScript]: How to refresh a Captcha?

Tags: php, javascript, refresh, captcha

I am showing Captcha in this way:

```
<img src="ReturnCaptcha2.php" alt="CAPTCHA" width="100" height="50">
```

I have a hyperlink named "Reload" near it. I want to recall that PHP file without refreshing my page. Probably, AJAX is involved in it. Please assist.

Comment: added more relevant tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use http://recaptcha.net/ and save yourself the trouble of it all? They will just handle the Captcha for you.

Here is some integration info on PHP and recaptcha:
[http://www.google.com/recaptcha/plugins/php](http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/)

as I mentioned, it is not difficult at all to integrate into your webapp.  Give it a try!

Comment: Its extremely easy, they make it 1 single include and you make an output. What did you have trouble with?  You make an include and you provide your recaptcha unique key.

Comment: @Jakub: I had problem setting up the keys for the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't there some parameter with a timestamp or something, so that the request does not get cached? Why not substitute the src with something like (using jquery)

```
$("img#your-selector").attr("src","ReturnCaptcha2.php?_="+((new Date()).getTime()));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Reload Image" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'cimage.php?' + Math.random(); 
   return false">
   <img src="cimage.php" alt="Enter captcha" title="Enter captcha" id="captcha"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use with Secureimage PHP Captcha.

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="0b21dde61d891cd" />
<img id="siimage" src="securimage_show.php?sid=2ef186788e" alt="CAPTCHA Image" width="126" height="36" /><br />
<input type="text" name="code" /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('siimage').src = 'securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">Reload Image</a>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
function reloadCaptcha()
{
img = document.getElementById('captcha');
img.src = 'ReturnCaptcha2.php';
}
```

And then add a button with `onclick="reloadCaptcha();"`.

I haven't tested it, and I'm no js guru, so not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

one more approach can be use a little ajax..
on your refresh button give the action as:
onclick=javascript:reloadCaptcha();

in this reloadCaptcha function,
give a call to your captcha.php and update the div holding your captcha 
with the return value. 
you can easily return a html and then embed it in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one.

It creates global variable. Checks for existance.

```
function get_captcha(){
    //get original url refresh
    console.log('captcha requested.');
    if(typeof window.captcha_src === 'undefined'){
        window.captcha_src = document.getElementById('captcha').src;
    }
    document.getElementById('captcha').src = window.captcha_src + '&nocache=' + Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even make a link and reload your captcha in same division. If it's not a problem.

`Enter Image Text <input name="captcha" type="text">
<img src="captcha.php" /><br> 
<a href="captcha.php">Reload Captcha</a><br/>`

Answer (score -1):

well i have solved this problem with a simple trick;
instead of putting the captcha in `<img>` put that in an `<iframe>`
and use javascript to reload it when u require

Javascript To Reload:

```
function reloadCaptcha()

{
document.getElementById('cap').src='captcha.php';
}
```

Actual HTML:

`<iframe id="cap" src="captcha.php"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="reload" onclick="reloadCaptcha();"/>`

it solves my problem,
correct me if i am wrong somewhere

Answer (score -2):

**@meme:**
I use same thing, but with jquery. If you need a few capthcas in one page:

```
<img class="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image">
<a class="capcha-refresh" href="#" ><img src="/images/Refresh-icon.png"></a>
```

And js function:

```
$('.capcha-refresh').click(function(a){
       $('.captcha').attr('src','/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random());
       a.preventDefault();
})
```